# MongoDB aggregation query - return all items inside nested subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Basically, I have a nested array of objects. I want to extract information from those objects, and return all the results as an array.

Here is my data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "608642db80a36336946620aa",
    "title": "titleHere",
    "types": {
      "flashcardReversed": [
        {
          "normal": { // the data inside of "normal" should become its own object in the returned array
            "_id": "608d5b290e635ece6828141X",
            "front": "2front",
            "back": "2back"
          },
          "reversed": { // the data inside of "reversed" should become its own object in the returned array
            "_id": "608t5b290e635ece6828141Y",
            "front": "2frontReversed",
            "back": "2backReversed"
          }
        },
        {
          "normal": {
            "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253726X",
            "front": "2front2",
            "back": "2back2"
          },
          "reversed": {
            "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253726Y",
            "front": "2frontReversed2",
            "back": "2backReversed2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the desired result:

```
[
  {
    "flashcardReversed": [
      {
        "_id": "608d5b290e635ece6828141X",
        "front": "2front",
        "back": "2back"
      },
      {
        "_id": "608t5b290e635ece6828141Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed",
        "back": "2backReversed"
      },
      {
        "_id": "608t5b290e635ece6828141Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed",
        "back": "2backReversed"
      },
      {
        "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253726Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed2",
        "back": "2backReversed2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current attempt: https://mongoplayground.net/p/k3Fjd59KMKg
I have tried merging the `$card` and `$card2` documents through various methods, and then using `$replaceRoot` to create the desired result - but after much time trying, I was unsuccessful.

Some notes about my use-case -
I will be using this pipeline inside `$facet`
There will be many objects inside of `flashcardReversed`, all created from the same Mongoose Schema

The document should have a max of ~2000 cards. I need the results for use in a react website. Should I be worried about the efficiency of this search? (if this should be a question in itself I would be happy to move it).

If my Mongoose Schemas would be helpful, let me know and I can add them.

All help is appreciated,

`-  Riley Swinson`

Comment: Is it always "normal" and "reversed" keys in the original? Or can there be more ?

Comment: @CodyＧ there can be many documents, all with the same structure. I'll clarify my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with

- $unwind to split the flash card array
- $project to convert the object containing normal/reverse to an array
- $unwind the created array
- $group by _id and collect the values in an array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$types.flashcardReversed"},
  {$project: {
      flashcardReversed: [
        "$types.flashcardReversed.normal",
        "$types.flashcardReversed.reversed"
      ]
  }},
  {$unwind: "$flashcardReversed"},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      flashcardReversed: {$push: "$flashcardReversed"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - I appreciate it. I noticed an error in my question - because I am using `$facet`, I already have`"flashcardReversed" as the parent: []`. 
How would I return just what is inside of  the `flashcardReversed` array in your result?

Comment: Use a $replaceRoot stage

Comment: tried, but got error `$replaceRoot must be of type object`. 
Attempted to use $arrayToObject, but I think I need a different object structure for that to work?

Comment: `{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$flashcardReversed"}}`

Comment: Yes, exactly what I tried, and still returns an error - https://mongoplayground.net/p/CiaOOrzzw5i. The goal would be to remove all the contents from the array - since $facet is already an array

[this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-move-an-array-of-embedded-documents-up-to-parent-and-change-key-value-with-aggregation-pipeline) seems like it could be a solution

Comment: ah, remove the final `$group` stage.  No need to  rejoin them in an array just to split them out again. https://mongoplayground.net/p/zsQsT4eIBGx

Comment: This was painfully obvious and I regret not having seen it sooner. Thanks for the additional help!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come up with this query to get the desired result

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$types.flashcardReversed"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "flashcardReversed": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$types.flashcardReversed"
          },
          "as": "elem",
          "in": "$$elem.v"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$flashcardReversed"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": 1,
      "flashcardReversed": {
        "$push": "$flashcardReversed"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Explanation of the above pipeline :

1. Use `$unwind` to divide the array into its elements
2. Use `$project` along with `$map` to convert the `flashcardReversed` object into an array of values. Using `$map` allows the pipeline to handle any additional keys on top of normal and reversed
3. Use `$unwind` to again split the flashcardReversed array formed in step 2
4. Use `$group` with the `$push` accumulator to add all values of `flashcardReversed` in a single array
5. Use `$project` to remove the `_id` field from the response

Here's a Mongodb playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KfIl-0pUgPo) for the same